# Large DataFrame with random columns of a smaller one (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am trying to generate a huge dataset in Python 3.6 using Pandas for testing a code but the method I developed is too slow and I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

I create a smaller dataframe with a few columns and around 3 millions of rows (for example):

```
# assume we have relevant information in 'a','b','c'
data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(int(3e6)))
data['a'] = 0 
data['b'] = 0
data['c'] = 0
```

Now, I would like to take random rows of this dataframe and build with them a bigger one with approximately 15 million rows, of course, even if rows repeat.

I tried taking samples and appending to the new dataframe like this:

```
data_tot = pd.DataFrame(columns=data.columns)

for i in range(int(15e6)):
    samp = data.sample(1)
    data_tot = data_tot.append(samp)
```

It looks very inefficient but I never had to generate such amount of data. I also tried preallocation and using iloc then, but still very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.random.choice`, generate random indices, and index `df`.

```
idx = np.random.choice(len(df), int(15e6))
df = df.iloc[idx, :]
```

Comment: That's it, but in the second instruction you switched the iloc parameters, it would be: df.iloc[ idx , : ] . Thanks a lot!